# Formatting Outlook email in Perl

Tags: perl, email, outlook, formatting, bold

I'm very new to Perl and have tried to adapt a script that a previous colleague has put together to send out emails. I've got it all working fine however I want make some characters bold so they stand out in the email.

The words I specifically want to bold are in the @msgbody.

```
my @msgbody=(
"Dear Stakeholders," ,
                 "\r Please be advised of the following upcoming works affecting all employer name applications. " ,
                 "\r Service Now Change Record: $string1 - $string2 " ,
                 "\r Scheduled Period: $TStartTime $DStartDate " .
                 "and $TEndTime $DEndDate " .
                 "(AEST)." ,
                 "\r Expected Outage Period:  " ,
                 "\r Affected Users: All users of Employer " ,
                 "\r Implementation: $string3 " ,
                 "\r A S Escalation Manager: Generic Name " ,
                 "\r Kind regards"
            );
```

Comment: You'll have to send your e-mail in HTML format and set the contant type of the message accordingly. Which Perl module do you use to send the e-mails?

Comment: If you don't want to use HTML, many email clients display text enclosed in * with bold formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the email that you're sending is in plain text format. And plain text doesn't support bold characters.

In order to include bold characters, you would need to switch to sending your email in HTML and adding MIME headers. That's not particularly difficult to do, but it would be easier to help if we know more about how you were sending these emails. Which modules are you using to format and send your messages?

I'd recommend taking a look at [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can make multi-line strings in Perl. You can lay out the string just like you want it and avoid a lot of extra typing (especially when the message changes):

```
my $msgbody = "Dear Stakeholders

Please be advised of the following upcoming works affecting all employer name applications.
Service Now Change Record: $string1 - $string2
Scheduled Period: $TStartTime $DStartDate and $TEndTime $DEndDate (AEST).
Expected Outage Period:
Affected Users: All users of Employer
Implementation: $string3
A S Escalation Manager: Generic Name
Kind regards
";
```

A heredoc makes this slightly easier since you don't have to treat the first line special:

```
my $msgbody = <<"HERE";
Dear Stakeholders

Please be advised of the following upcoming works affecting all employer name applications.
Service Now Change Record: $string1 - $string2
Scheduled Period: $TStartTime $DStartDate and $TEndTime $DEndDate (AEST).
Expected Outage Period:
Affected Users: All users of Employer
Implementation: $string3
A S Escalation Manager: Generic Name
Kind regards
HERE
```

This is especially true once Perl v5.26 introduced the [indented heredoc](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/12/strip-leading-spaces-from-here-docs-with-v5-26/) that can strip leading space:

```
use v5.26;
my $msgbody = <<~"HERE";
    Dear Stakeholders

    Please be advised of the following upcoming works affecting all employer name applications.
    Service Now Change Record: $string1 - $string2
    Scheduled Period: $TStartTime $DStartDate and $TEndTime $DEndDate (AEST).
    Expected Outage Period:
    Affected Users: All users of Employer
    Implementation: $string3
    A S Escalation Manager: Generic Name
    Kind regards
    HERE
```